# Cocos2d-JS + third party application

Tags: android, cocos2d-js

How to tie Cocos2d-JS with admod ad? 
Wiki on cocos main site has info about plugin for linking 3rd application with c++ cocos application.
Does anyone know is it possible do with Cocos2d-JS ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to use plugin-x from the JS code but so far I was not able to use it myself.

Check this thread for additional details!